# Visual Studio shortcuts to MSDN

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, msdn

I'm using Visual Studio 2012 Professional. I was writing a simple function this morning, something like this example which is really not important:

```
    public DateTime getDeadline()
    {
        var deadline = DateTime.Now.Date;
        if (deadline.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Sunday)
                 return deadline.AddDays(-2);
        if (deadline.DayOfWeek == DayOfWeek.Saturday)
            return deadline.AddDays(-1);
        return deadline;
    }
```

I wanted to read more information about DateTime's "DayOfWeek" property from Microsoft's MSDN page. So I typed "DateTime.DayOfWeek" into Google search and naturally the first result is what I wanted.

My question is simple...  does Visual Studio 2012 have a way to get from the IDE directly to the MSDN page for a class or property so I don't have to use a web search?

Comment: Did you try pressing `F1`, with the caret in the bit you were interested in?

Comment: Also, depending on what you have installed you can right click - go to definition to get the implementation

Comment: Put the mouse cursor on the class/property and press F1 Key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put your cursor on the property and press F1 Key. That will take you to MSDN details.

For more see: [Visual Studio shortcut keys](http://www.dofactory.com/reference/visual-studio-shortcuts)

> <kbd>F1</kbd>
>
> Displays a topic from Help that corresponds to the part of the user
>   interface that currently has the focus. If the focus is in a source
>   window, Help will try to display a topic relevant to the text under
>   the cursor

Comment: I knew there was a shortcut! It looks like I'm on the right path, but pressing F1 takes me to an error page on MSDN that says "Unable to Service Request".

Comment: @laylarenee, strange, it works on my side, may be it has to do with your browser cache. See: [MSDN “Cannot Service Request” error](http://blog.mischel.com/2011/09/17/msdn-cannot-service-request-error/)

Comment: Fixed. My Firefox NoScript add-on was interfering with the MSDN request.